# Enable HTML5 and JS in webbrowser control for app to windows mobile 6.5

Tags: c#, mobile, visual-studio-2008, window, webbrowser-control

I'm going to create an application for Windows Mobile 6.5 in Visual Studio 2008, where the Framework it handles is 3.5, the WebBrowser control when it is tested on a device with WM6.5, does not detect JS controls or some applications with HTML5, one of The alternatives I found is to use WebKit, but I could not apply it in a form itself, any idea how to incorporate it or enable that option ?, thank you.

Comment: Maybe the browser definition is missing?

Comment: For desktop web controls you need to set a registry key for your app, or else the control runs as IE 7 to support legacy apps.  Mobile might be the same